# Navision Report Filter

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

Given a report with a data item *Customer* and a data item *SalesLine*.

I display all Saleslines from each Customer. How do I filter these Customers out which does not have Sales Line? Where do I need to put the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `OnAfterGetRecord` trigger for each *Customer*, do a count of their SalesLines and if the count is zero then use `CurrReport.Skip()` to skip that data item (*Customer*).

Something like this:

```
IF SalesLines.COUNT = 0 THEN BEGIN
  CurrReport.SKIP()
END
```